# iOS: How to reduce background activity in drive tracking app

Tags: ios, background, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that runs in the background and monitors the user drive.

The app stays alive in the background due to CLLocation background mode.

But the problem is that the app show background activity as 22 hours in last 24 hours. My understanding is that the background activity drains a lot of battery.

There are some drive tracking apps that have background activity approximately equal to the sum of all drive times. My app consumes 3 times more power than them.

How can i detect all user drives and at the same time also reduce background activity, thereby reducing battery consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Your application becomes active everytime didUpdateLocation delegate of CLLocationManager triggers the frequency in which CLLocationManager triggers delegate depends on the accuracy you have specified in your CLLocationManager configuration.

```
- (CLLocationManager *)defaultLocationManager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static CLLocationManager *locationManager = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers; //try setting accuracy filter to a value where it wont end up calling your delegate frequently yet gives you enough info about user location as per your need
        locationManager.distanceFilter=3000; //try setting distance filter to a value where it wont end up calling your delegate frequently yet gives you enough info about user location as per your need
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    });
    return locationManager;
}
```

Becareful while using background modes specially location updates. Apple very much likely to reject your app if you are making use of location updates for any other purpose then tracking the user location.

Apple expects you to add the statement in your app description clearly stating continued use of GPS will drain out battery.

Most of the time app don't need real time location updates. If yours is one such case and yet you want to track the user location, remove the background mode for location update and  try using `significantLocationChanges`

```
[[self defaultLocationManager] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

**Note :** for observing SignificantLocationChanges you dont need background modes capability and you will continue to recieve control even when your app is in background just like realtime location update.

Lesser accuracy, lesser power consumption lesser invocation of app :)

Hope my answer helped you :)

Comment: your answer is very helpful. My app tracks the user so location permission isn't a problem. But i would like to get the user location every 1 minute. How is that possible while conserving the battery life. My app needs user location only 1 hour during morning and 1 hour during evening.

Comment: First of all location services are not designed to work with time interval. Colocation manager triggers location update only when iPhone changes its location. It does make sense in all possible ways because if you have kept your iPhone on desk for 1 hr it's location is always the same believing your desk is stationary :p then why will it waste time triggering 60 times your app burning up the battery???? Can you please clarify why do you need location updates after every minute n why can't you relay on location filters ??? I believe if you are using location updates only for tracking user

Comment: Then distance filter must do the very fair job. Try setting distance filter  as accurate distance as you need set accuracy level to the most accurate one and you must be good to go :) as per power consumption is concerned if you start your background activity only for 2 hour then how come u noticed it to be active for 22 hours??? That means either you started and never stopped it at all :)  my suggestion because you can't make use of expiration handler or nstimer as app might pause between two location updates in such case your timer might stop as well so save the current time in

Comment: NSUserdefaults and the everytime you get location update check if the duration is less than an hour if yes process else stop monitoring location changes :) that will ensure your background activity won't run more than an hour :)  but yes cons are if user manually changes time while your app is in background them your logiic will be messed up :( but I believe that's the best you can do with it as you can run the timer continuously in background :) hope my suggestions made sense :)